# Accessing Object variables in a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I have a following design

```
function crudDataTable()
{
    this.addEditFormContainerSelector = ''; 
    this.paginationType = "full_numbers";  // Provide Pagination Type
    this.processing = true; 
    this.serverSide = true;  //I want this this to be accessible in fnRowCallback below:

    this.create = function(){

        this.tableInstance = $(this.tableLocationSelector).DataTable({
            "sPaginationType": this.paginationType
            fnRowCallback:function(nRow, aData) {
                // "this" from crudDataTable should be accessible here
            }  
        })
    }
}
```

I want the **`this`** from `crudDataTable` to be accessible in `fnRowCallback`.

How can I acheive this?, also the `fnRowCallback` is fired by the `datatable` component, so that's not in my control. How can I make **`this`** accessible under `fnRowCallback`.

Or if this is not possible, then what are the other approaches to achieve it?

I am trying to write a component, where users of these component can simply setup its variables and call the create function. I am facing this challenge of accessing **`this`** in the `fnRowCallback` function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a reference to `this` outside of the callback:

```
var table = this;
this.tableInstance = $(this.tableLocationSelector).DataTable({
     "sPaginationType": this.paginationType,
     fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData) {
         //Use `table` to refer to the instance of `crudDataTable`
     }  
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the ES5 [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (but be aware that older browsers don't support it):

```
this.tableInstance = $(this.tableLocationSelector).DataTable({
     "sPaginationType": this.paginationType,
     fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData) {
         //Use `this` to refer to the instance of `crudDataTable`
     }.bind(this);
});
```

Comment: would this `var table` be accessible inside fnRowCallback?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and providing its alternatives too!